# Internal Server Error when updating slug

Tags: craft3, error, server, slug, entry-slug

I'm getting an internal server error when I try to update the my entry's slug on prod, but not on dev or locally. It's happening across entries, it doesn't seem to be specific to a certain entry. Any ideas why this might be happening?[image]

Comment: Hey, I would delete the contents of /storage/logs on your production server then refresh this page to generate a new web.log file. The answer is likely in there, if it's cryptic then paste the contents of your log file into the question.

Comment: @dmatthams thanks - I'm getting `Request didn’t meet the user agent and IP requirement for maintaining a user session.` I've seen comments about checking the cpTrigger (it's currently set to "admin") but I'm not sure what to change it to/how it would help...

Comment: This is a very odd error, especially considering It only happens when changing a slug. Maybe someone else will have an answer, but I would probably give support@craftcms.com a go as I think this may be difficult to resolve here.

Comment: @Lisa Are you sure that's the error message of this particular request? Typically I've seen that "maintaining user session" error message in logs but it's with with bots hitting the site (because they don't accept cookies). While not recommended for production, if you turn on devMode temporarily (which can be easier than sifting through the log files),  hit the CP again and see what happens then turn it off right away (so you don't forget to leave it on).

Comment: Turns out it was an error with the router plugin - it was struggling because we had tried to use a special character in a slug, and that just triggered a slew of errors. Thanks for the help!!